# Why are there entries in sessions table for uid 0?

Tags: sessions

I was alarmed to find sessions being written to the table [sessions] for uid 0. Do I need to worry or is this normal? I could not find answers by searching. I don't know how the sessions table works.
This is Drupal 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not be alarmed, this is normal. Typically seen in Drupal Commerce sites to keep track of anonymous users also known as user 0.

Comment: Thank you. That's a relief.